# Fixing android softkeyboard issues

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a ListAdapter that displays View with contains an Edittext.
When that view is focused the softkeyboard pops up.
However for some reason that causes the view to lose focus. 
Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[It is possible to have items in a ListView gain focus](http://groups.google.nl/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8cedf0199a958762), but [it isn't designed for that](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/50f0fc185da8fe4d) and may require some hackery.